# Django model update on fetch

Tags: python, django

My model has a field that should change if it's within a date range.

It would look like this:

```
class Election(models.Model)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'Start Date')
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'End date')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def updateActive(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        if self.start_date < now and self.end_date > now:
            self.active=True
        else:
            self.active=False
        self.save()
```

RIght now, every time I query for this model, I call `updateActive()` from my `views.py`.

So, my question is: Is there a way to call `updateActive()` every time I fetch an `Election` object? Or keeping it constant updated?

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Would it be an option to not store it at all, but just compute it whenever it's needed?

Comment: That's what I've been doing until now. I was just wondering if there was a way to automate this.

Comment: Not sure about auto updating, but the logic looks wrong: `if self.start_date > now and self.end_date < now:` - this would mean that `start_date > end_date` which is probably not what you want. Try `self.active = start_date < timezone.now() < end_date; self.save()`

Comment: Whoops. Fixed on the question. The question still remains.

Comment: Have you considered using a [model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/)?

Comment: Great. Didn't know about custom managers. Thanks!

Comment: @Pabs no worries. I realise that my comment was really obscure but hopefully you'll manage from there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method would be not to have the `active` field at all in your model. The main reason is that when a value can be generated from a simple calculation, it should not be stored in the database. The second reason is that BooleanField cannot be effectively indexed and queries involving this field will be slow. Therefore you do not lose anything by doing the calculation instead of doing the field. The best way is to add a custom queryset like this:

```
class ElectionQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def is_active(self):
        return self.filter(start_date__lt=timezone.now()).filter(end_date__gt=timezone.now())
```

Now your model is really simple.

class Election(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'Start Date')
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'End date')

```
objects = ElectionQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Now your model is realy simple.

```
class Election(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'Start Date')
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'End date')

    objects = ElectionQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Yes that's all. There is no need to update the database everytime you fetch an object!  You can use a simple method to find out what's active or not

```
Election.objects.is_active()
```

The result from is_active is a queryset, and you can chain it as usual

```
Election.objects.is_active().filter(...)
```

if you want to check if an election is active in the template you can do :

```
class Election(models.Model):
    def is_active()
         if self.start_date < now and self.end_date > now:
            return True
```

Comment: This works great in the model, but I'm a bit lost on how to call a custom manager in an html template..

Comment: Templates were not mentioned in the original question. You can't anyway access the manager from the template (custom or default).

Comment: I noticed. I just passed different querysets to my html and its working well. Thank you for tour answer.

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom manager for the model. While you can set the active attribute for the instances in the query itself, it doesn't seem correct from a design point of view(A get method shouldn't mutate the data it is querying). It makes sense to have an active attribute as you may want to invalidate a certain instance later manually.
You could either update the active field using a background job, this way your manager would look like

```
class ElectionManager(models.Manager):
def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().filter(active=True)
class Election(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'Start Date')
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'End date')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    elections = ElectionManager()
```

This way Election.elections.all() would return only active elections.
If you want to filter out the query via a class method, then you can use list comprehension or generators to get the required queryset in the ElectionManager.get_queryset method.

Comment: Although interesting, not quite what I intend, since I have a view that shows a table with all the passed, in progress and upcoming elections. That's why I want the active tag to be updated.